# GraphicsMagick montage with border with rotation

Tags: image, graphics, graphicsmagick

I'm attempting to use GraphicsMagick's montage tool to rotate 2 images, place a border around each one individually and set the background color to blue.  However, I can only successfully rotate the image OR set a border, but not both at the same time.  Is this per design? or a bug? Or am I just calling it wrong?

Here's the command I'm running

`gm montage -background blue -borderwidth 5 -bordercolor white -rotate 15 <input1>.jpg <input2>.jpg <output>.jpg`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you could do it with ImageMagick, but GraphicsMagick doesn't, indeed, seem to want to do rotation and borders.

`1.png` is a red square

`2.png` is a blue square

```
{ convert -background cyan -bordercolor lime  1.png -rotate 15 -border 5 miff:-; convert -background yellow -bordercolor magenta  2.png -rotate 15 -border 5 miff:-; } | montage -background blue miff:- result.jpg
```

[image]

Another option for ImageMagick is like this:

```
convert -background cyan -bordercolor lime  1.png -rotate 15 -border 5 \( -background yellow -bordercolor magenta  2.png -rotate 15 -border 5 \) +append result.png
```

[image]

or this:

```
convert -background cyan -bordercolor lime  1.png -rotate 15 -border 5 \
 \( -background yellow -bordercolor magenta  2.png -rotate 15 -border 5 \) \
 -append result.png
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response! I should've clarified that I'm wanting to have the border rotate with the image as well, if that makes sense...is this possible?

Comment: My computer is off, but move the `-border` before `-rotate` on the commandline.